# count how many times a letter exist in an string (ruby)

Tags: ruby

I'm making a hangman game in ruby. Everything works, except one thing. I cant really explain what I need so I made a example:

```
string = 'cheese'
lives = 'what code goes here?'
```

In this case, i have to count 'c', 'h', 's' and only one 'e', so that the lives variable is equal to 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like so?

```
> 'cheese'.chars.uniq.length
=> 4
```

Comment: Pretty hard to beat that.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! You really helped me out :)